# Parts of string in bold text

Tags: javascript

I have a unordered list that contains

```
<ul id="strip">
     <li><a href="#"><span>This-is a test string</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>This is without</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>New-test</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to bold the text before the "-", so in the first `<li>` "This" is bolded.

I'm stuck in the loop where I should find the "-".

NB: Regular JavaScript, no JQuery :-)

Comment: i'm simply curious: why no jQuery?

Comment: Is the down vote for 'no jQuery'?

Comment: My bad, didn't read the "no jQuery" part. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `stringObject.replace(findstring,newstring)` method.
In your case `liString.replace(/\b(.*?-.*?)\b/,"<strong>$1</strong>")`
full solution:

```
var lists = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var listsL = lists.length;

for (var i = 0; i < listsL; ++i){
   liString = lists[i].innerHTML;
   liString = liString.replace(/\b([^-]*-[^\b]*?)\b/,"<strong>$1</strong>");
   lists[i].innerHTML = liString;
}
```