# Bold part of String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

What is the best way to bold a part of string in Javascript?

I have an array of objects. Each object has a name. There is also an input parameter.

If, for example, you write "sa" in input, it automatically searches in array looking for objects with names that contain "sa" string.

When I print all the names, I want to bold the part of the name that coincide with the input text.

For example, if I search for "Ma":

**Ma**ria 
A**ma**ria 
etc...

I need a solution that doesn't use jQuery. Help is appreciated.

PD: The final strings are in the

tag. I create a list using angular ng-repeat.

This is the code:

```
$scope.users = data;
                for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                  data[i].name=data[i].name.replace($scope.modelCiudad,"<b>"+$scope.modelCiudad+"</b>");
                };
```

ModelCiudad is the input text content var. And data is the array of objects.

In this code if for example ModelCiudad is "ma" the result of each

is:

```
<b>Ma</b>ria
```

not **Ma**ria

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parts of string in bold text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270424/parts-of-string-in-bold-text)

Comment: please share what you tried.

Comment: A more appropriate tag than `<b>` might be `<mark>`, which represents text that is highlighted for its relevance in a particular context. Highlighting search matches is a perfect use of the `<mark>` tag.

Comment: I think you're handling replacing properly. It seems all the answers show you how to replace text, when the real problem seems to be how the data is rendering. It all depends how you render/set this text. It seems if you set the `innerHTML` to your string it'll render properly, but if you set the `innerText` or `textContent` it will render the `<b>` tags literally rather than render them as HTML.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use Javascript's `str.replace()` method, where `str` is equal to all of the text you want to search through.

```
var str = "Hello";
var substr = "el";
str.replace(substr, '<b>' + substr + '</b>');
```

The above will only replace the first instance of `substr`. If you want to handle replacing multiple substrings within a string, you have to use a regular expression with the `g` modifier.

```
function boldString(str, substr) {
  var strRegExp = new RegExp(substr, 'g');
  return str.replace(strRegExp, '<b>'+substr+'</b>');
}
```

In practice calling `boldString` would looks something like:

```
boldString("Hello, can you help me?", "el"); 
// Returns: H<b>el</b>lo can you h<b>el</b>p me?
```

Which when rendered by the browser will look something like: H**el**lo can you h**el**p me?

Here is a JSFiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/1rennp8r/3/

---

A concise ES6 solution could look something like this:

```
const boldString = (str, substr) => str.replace(RegExp(substr, 'g'), `<b>${substr}</b>`);
```

Where `str` is the string you want to modify, and `substr` is the substring to bold.

---

ES12 introduces a new string method `str.replaceAll()` which obviates the need for regex if replacing all occurrences at once. It's usage in this case would look something like this:

```
const boldString = (str, substr) => str.replaceAll(substr, `<b>${substr}</b>`);
```

---

I should mention that in order for these latter approaches to work, your environment must support ES6/ES12 (or use a tool like Babel to transpile).

Another important note is that all of these approaches are *case sensitive*.

Comment: Hi Michel! I tested you solution, but doesn't work. The result if i have your example is: All of the <b>te</b>xt you want to search through.

Comment: I've updated my answer with better code and a jsfiddle

Comment: I understand you code michel. If you can see my updated question. I use angular for create a list of names using the data[x].name. The b tag is converted to string. :(

Comment: Well first try implementing my code above because replace will only find the first instance of a match, this above code will go through the whole string.
It might be a better idea to do the search and bold function after the text has been rendered, as opposed to storing the result and then rendering it

Comment: I this case, not change the string, not are bold and not are b tag. I don't update the innerhtml of <li>'s because the list it's dinamical. When user write another letter, the list changes. I'ts posible that are here the issue? I could execute a function when user write another letter that actualize all new created li's, but i would change the string before create the li's. PD: if Use Div tag the problem is the same

Comment: @MichaelHamilton, your solution works for finding the exact character. What if you want to find the character in both lowercase and uppercase? I know RegExp(find, 'ga') will find it but then the original string will no longer have the original casing. So if the user search for 'ma', Maria will be changed to **ma**ria

Comment: I have `a.textContent = \`<b>${dateString}</b>\``. It does not interpret the b tag, how can I do that?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a pure JS solution that **preserves the original case** (ignoring the case of the query thus):

```
const boldQuery = (str, query) => {
    const n = str.toUpperCase();
    const q = query.toUpperCase();
    const x = n.indexOf(q);
    if (!q || x === -1) {
        return str; // bail early
    }
    const l = q.length;
    return str.substr(0, x) + '<b>' + str.substr(x, l) + '</b>' + str.substr(x + l);
}
```

Test:

```
boldQuery('Maria', 'mar'); // "<b>Mar</b>ia"
boldQuery('Almaria', 'Mar'); // "Al<b>mar</b>ia"
```

Comment: This is the answer for case insensitive search

Comment: This method only applies the bolding to the first occurrence. ie boldQuery('Barbara', 'ar') will result in 'B<b>ar</b>bara'

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem today - except I wanted to match whole words and not substrings. so if `const text = 'The quick brown foxes jumped'` and `const word = 'foxes'` than I want the result to be `'The quick brown <strong>foxes</strong> jumped'`; however if `const word = 'fox'`, than I expect no change.

I ended up doing something similar to the following:

```
const pattern = `(\\s|\\b)(${word})(\\s|\\b)`;
const regexp = new RegExp(pattern, 'ig'); // ignore case (optional) and match all
const replaceMask = `$1<strong>$2</strong>$3`;

return text.replace(regexp, replaceMask);
```

First I get the exact word which is either before/after some whitespace or a word boundary, and then I replace it with the same whitespace (if any) and word, except the word is wrapped in a `<strong>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version I came up with if you want to style words or individual characters at their index in react/javascript.

```
replaceAt( yourArrayOfIndexes, yourString/orArrayOfStrings )
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ov7zxp9mjq

```
function replaceAt(indexArray, [...string]) {
    const replaceValue = i => string[i] = <b>{string[i]}</b>;
    indexArray.forEach(replaceValue);
    return string;
}
```

And here is another alternate method

```
function replaceAt(indexArray, [...string]) {
    const startTag = '<b>';
    const endTag = '</b>';
    const tagLetter = i => string.splice(i, 1, startTag + string[i] + endTag);
    indexArray.forEach(tagLetter);
    return string.join('');
}
```

And another...

```
function replaceAt(indexArray, [...string]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
        string = Object.assign(string, {
          [indexArray[i]]: <b>{string[indexArray[i]]}</b>
        });
    }
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions are great, but are limited! Imagine a test scenerio where you want to match case insensitive query in a string and they could be multiple matches.

For example

Query: ma

String: The Amazing Spiderman

Expected Result: The A**ma**zing Spider**ma**n

For above scenerio, use this:

```
const boldMatchText = (text,searchInput) => {
let str = text.toLowerCase();
const query = searchInput.toLowerCase();
let result = "";
let queryLoc = str.indexOf(query);

if (queryLoc === -1) {
  result += text;
} else
  do {
    result += ` ${text.substr(0, queryLoc)}
    <b>${text.substr(queryLoc, query.length)}</b>`;
    str = str.substr(queryLoc + query.length, str.length);
    text = text.substr(queryLoc + query.length, str.length);
    queryLoc = str.indexOf(query);
  } while (text.length > 0 && queryLoc !== -1);

return result + text;


};
```