# I need to make some part of my string bold using replace function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to make some part of my string bold using the replace function. "b" and "strong" tags do not work within the string as "<" part of tag displays in the output for milliseconds which is quite unprofessional. I am unable to apply this function

```js
boldString(str, substr) {
  var strRegExp = new RegExp(substr, 'g');
  return str.replace(strRegExp, '<b>'+substr+'</b>');
}
```

I think it might work or please give me some alternate solution. Thanks

```js
function startTyping(){

  var bt = document.getElementById("typBt");
    bt.style.display = "none";

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    task(i);
  }
}

function task(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Add tasks to do 
    var typeString = ['\u2022 A quick brown fox \r  jumps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F\n\n\u2022 A quick brown fox \r  jumps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F\n\n\u2022 A quick broum fox \r  jumnps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F\n\n\u2022 A quick brown fox \r  jumps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F\n\n\u2022 A quick brown fox \r  jumps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F'];

    var i = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var selectedText = '';
    var text = '';
    var typing = document.getElementById('typing');

    (function type() {
      if (count == typeString.length) {
        count = 0;
      };

      selectedText = typeString[count];
      text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
      typing.innerHTML = text.fontsize(3);
      typing.style.fontFamily = "helveticanew";
      typing.style.color = "black";
      typing.style.fontWeight = "normal";
      typing.style.lineHeight = "1"; //Difference between different lines  
      typing.style.textAlign = "left";
      typing.style.margin = "25px";

      if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
        count++;
        i = 0;
      }

      /* SOLUTION : wait two seconds when new line */
      if (typeString[0][i - 1] == '\n') {
        setTimeout(type, 1000); //Time delay between two bullets
      } else if (count === 1) {
        setTimeout(type, 5000); //Time delay after typing is finished
      } else {
        setTimeout(type, 40); //Typing speed
      }
    }());

  }, 1000);//Start time


}


// uni code for bullet "\u2022"
// uni code for tick mark "\u2714\uFE0F"
// line break "\r"
// line break for new bullet "/n"
```

```css
#typBt {
  background-color: green;
  border: 20px solid;
  color: black;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline overline;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 50px 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline:none
}
```

```html
    <pre id="typing"></pre>
    
    <button id="typBt" onclick="startTyping()">Show Typing</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bold part of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896907/bold-part-of-string)

Comment: Your code is rather strange, including using the deprecated fontsize function, and it kind of goes back and forth putting characters in then taking them out. It might be wise to go through it line by line making sure you understand it completely before trying to parse extras like HTML elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you know the text to be put in bold... There is a JS string function bold().

This can help you...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a string in bold.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Hello World!";
  var result = "The " + str.bold() + " is in bold";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Check: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_str_bold

Comment: [.bold()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold) is deprecated