# How to make some special character string as bold in javascript while using text plugin

Tags: javascript, html, string, web, frontend

i want to make this text "|| something 1 || something 2 || more || last one ||"

and then bold "|" all that string

then its became something this "**||** something 1 **||** something 2 **||** more **||** last one **||**"

I'm using typewriter text plugin from gsap
this is my code

```
function boldString(str, substr) {
            var strRegExp = new RegExp(substr, 'g');
            return str.replace(strRegExp, '<b>' + substr + '</b>');
        }

gsap.to('.lead', { duration: '3.5', delay: '2', text: boldString("|| something 1 || something 2 || more || last one ||", "|")
```

then give me this result after typewriter plugin successfully launch

"||||| |s|o|m|e|t|h|i|n|g| |1| ||||| |s|o|m|e|t|h|i|n|g| |2| ||||| |m|o|r|e| ||||| |l|a|s|t| |o|n|e| |||||"

but with some "|" are bold

[image]

I'm also modified my code into

```
return str.replace(substr, '<b>' + substr + '</b>');
```

then gave me this result

**|**| something 1 || something 2 || more || last one ||

this is my reference before: [Bold part of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896907/bold-part-of-string)

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

Escape the pipe with a backslash:

```js
var str = "||||| |s|o|m|e|t|h|i|n|g| |1| ||||| |s|o|m|e|t|h|i|n|g| |2| ||||| |m|o|r|e| ||||| |l|a|s|t| |o|n|e| |||||";

var result = str.replace(/\|/gi, '<b>|</b>');

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work for my case. Thanks for your time, have a nice day :)

Comment: as I mentioned before, it doesn't work. it opposing all bold effects str on my case.
the best modification of my code  based on your answer, get me to result as picture [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiEs2.png) I gave in my question but your code gave me the opposite bold effect (string that wasn't bold now get bold, and string that was bold now get normal str). I'm suspecting its because of GSAP typewriter plugin

I'm working like half of the day just for your answer until I gave up and posting that comment :)

Comment: here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/c0op1vk2/1/) to see my code based on your answer

Some modification doesn't even show at all. that's why i gave up on this