# How do i bold text that is higlighted in javascript?

Tags: javascript, highlight

I am trying to find a way to let you bold the text that is highlighted. I have no idea on how to do this. Any help?

```
/* my code so far: */ window.highlightedText.bold();
```

Comment: Where is this text that you are trying to bold? That is the first question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Comment: Related: [How can I dynamically highlight strings on a web page?](/a/32167527/4642212).

Comment: Relevant questions: [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text), [Bold part of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896907/bold-part-of-string)